# jQuery fixed position resizeable list?

Tags: jquery, list, scroll, positioning

I have made a drag-to-trigger_event page based on [this guide](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/drag-to-share/).

I'm displaying list of images in the center of the screen, and sometimes page is larger than window size, so I have to use 'position:fixed' for it to always display in the center of the sreen.

I've made a tweak that instead of showing simple tooltips after hovering on an icon I display a list of options and after dropping it on an option it causes different reaction.

So, my problem is that when list of option is really long (user-defined) then page is too small to display whole list. With 'position:absolute' there is no problem, becouse scrollbars appear and user can scroll down to last positions of the list. But with 'position:fixed' there is no way that user could see the whole list becouse scrolling scrolls through whole page with the list fixed in place and whole list is not visible.

Is there any solution for that problem? Maybe a simple multi-column list or a 'invisible' scroll only for that list? Or any other simplier solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by dynamically modifying margin-top in window.onScroll() function and still having position:absolute enabling me to view every item on the list.

Answer (score 0):

try to give:-

use anyone of them:-

```
position: absolute;
position:relative;
position:fixed;

display: inline-block;
```

visit this link for your solution once:-

http://www.dougboude.com/blog/1/2008/05/Viewing-Option-Text-in-IE7-thats-Wider-than-the-Select-List.cfm

Comment: Three at once? No, list items that don't fit on the screen still aren't displayed. I think that last position declared is always valid in css.

Comment: if i am not wrong you want to something like , u have dropdown u want it to resizable according to data .. m i correct??

Comment: Could you please explain why you are defining three `position`?

Comment: Yes, I want a dropdown list resizeable according to data, and as Starx said could you please explain why three position attributes?

Comment: i m just telling u can use this also... even one of them.. not all three at a time.. give absolute and give diplay inline-block .. try this;;

Comment: Well, it isn't a solution, becouse I obviosly tried that and It didn't help, so I've posted this question. The container has to be fixed and later the list is relative to parents.

Comment: Yes, but it's not a solution for me. I'm fetching with AJAX and adding dynamically list items into the list and width is not an issue, because it automatically add newlines when text is too long. Issue is only height and lack of ability to view whole list when position of image container is fixed.